# Benefit of Dell PERC Card for SSD

Tags: configuration, hardware, ssd, dell-perc

I bought a dell workstation for using with mysql and python.  It came with a single HD and PERC 310 controller.  I then installed the OS on an ssd instead to speed things up.  However, there seems to be a problem with perc and ssd, such that trim does not work and the ssd is much slower.  Im not curious as to 'how to solve my problem', this question is strictly, what is the benefit of the PERC controller over directly connecting to the sata III.   Is it only useful in RAID configurations or should it never be used with an SSD?

Answer (score 1):

In your specific, non-server, workstation situation with a consumer SSD, you should probably just connect the SSD to the SATA motherboard port. It's your best option.

There's no benefit to a RAID controller in this very narrow case.

TRIM is really not a factor with enterprise SSD setups, and there's a lot more detail than can be covered within the scope of this question.